# Adding Date Label to a GIF generated in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have the following code but I don't know why is not adding any date label to the GIF. I'm new in GEE.

```
var coleccion = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
.filterBounds(geometry)
.filterDate("2022-01-01", "2023-03-01")
.filterMetadata("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", "less_than", 5)
.map(function(i){
   return i.select(["B4", "B3", "B2"]).clip(geometry)
})


var col = coleccion.map(function(img) {
  var doy = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')).getRelative('day', 'year');
  return img.set('doy', doy);
});


var distinctDOY = col.filterDate('2022-01-01', '2023-01-01');
var filter = ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'doy', rightField: 'doy'});
var join = ee.Join.saveAll('doy_matches');
var joinCol = ee.ImageCollection(join.apply(distinctDOY, col, filter));

// Apply median reduction among matching DOY collections.
var comp = joinCol.map(function(img) {
  var doyCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
    img.get('doy_matches')
  );
  return doyCol.reduce(ee.Reducer.median())
    .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start']);
});

var visParams = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 9000.0,
  
};

var text = require('users/gena/packages:text')
// get text location
var pt = text.getLocation(geometry, 'right', '2%', '35%')

// Create RGB visualization images for use as animation frames.
var rgbVis = comp.map(function(img) {
  var scale = 15000
  var textVis = { fontSize: 32, textColor: 'ffffff', outlineColor: '000000', outlineWidth: 2.5, outlineOpacity: 0.6 }
  var label = text.draw(img.get('system:index'), pt, scale, textVis)
  
  return img.visualize(visParams).blend(label)
});

// Define GIF visualization arguments.
var gifParams = {
  'region': geometry,
  'dimensions': 600,
  'crs': 'EPSG:3857',
  'framesPerSecond': 2,
  'format': 'gif'
};

// Print the GIF URL to the console.
print(rgbVis.getVideoThumbURL(gifParams));

// Render the GIF animation in the console.
print(ui.Thumbnail(rgbVis, gifParams));
```